# Update text of card in Google Glass using GDK?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm interested in changing the text of a card based on some event. Is it possible to change the text of card without calling `setContentView()` on the Activity?

Once the card has been converted into view and set using `setContentView()`, I haven't found a way to change its contents without calling 'setContentView()' again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getView()` method of the `Card` builder class returns an Android `View` version of the `Card` that is a snapshot.

Modifying the original `Card` will not modify the `View` you retrieved earlier. This means that the only way to update your content view is to generate a new `View` with `getView()` and set it with `setContentView()`.